# Does java world has the counterpart Regexp::Optimizer in perl?

Tags: java, regex

using perl's Regexp::Optimizer, it can be achived

```
use Regexp::Optimizer;
my $o  = Regexp::Optimizer->new->optimize(qr/foobar|fooxar|foozap/);
# $re is now qr/foo(?:[bx]ar|zap)/
```

by not continuing matching when the common prefix(in this case it is 'foo') is not found, that can gain great performance as the common regular expression engine is NFA. 
I am wondering if the java world has the counterpart Regexp::Optimizer?

Comment: Note that Perl itself performs that very optimsiation automatically since 5.10. (Actually, it uses a trie instead of char classes and alternations, so one could say Perl 5.10 is even better than R::O!)

Comment: @Jim Garrison, The linked post is far more general, to the point that the answers don't apply. Not a dupe.